# Navigate to Fragment which is not in current Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

I use this code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16044189/2047987) to create a Flip Card Animation for older Android devices. Now I want to flip to a Fragment which is not in the current Activity. I tried with this code:

```
MyFragment f = new MyFragment();

getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.item_detail_container, f).commit();
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();

f.getView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
View root = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);

FlipAnimation flipAnimation = new FlipAnimation(this.getView(), f.getView());
root.startAnimation(flipAnimation);
```

But then it comes to a NullPointerException on `toView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` in the FlipAnimation class. How can I flip to a Fragment which is not in the current Activity?

**EDIT: I solve the question with the answer 1 and the comments from it. The Code here is updated and works fine now.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`commit()` on a `FragmentTransaction` is not immediate. It is asynchronous. Hence, by the time `commit()` returns, your fragment has not been called with `onCreateView()` yet, and therefore `getView()` returns `null`.

I would think that the right answer would be for you to be applying your animations right in the `FragmentTransaction` via `setCustomAnimations()`.

Beyond that, you could try to `post()` your work to do the `FlipAnimation`, so it occurs after the transaction has been completed.

Comment: I think the olution with with `setCustomAnimations()` does not work on older devices because I have to give some xml resources to the method and in the xml are ObjectAnimator which only work on Android > 3.0 The solution with post should work I think. But how should I give the FlipAnimation Object to the Method and on which Fragment do I have to call it? Can you please give me a sample code?

Comment: @Cilenco: I have never tried performing an animation the way you are, so I do not have any sample code. I am merely pointing out that you cannot do your animation where you are, because the `View` you wish to animate does not exist. You might consider only doing the animations on devices that support `setCustomAniamtions()`.

Comment: I got it :) `commit() on a FragmentTransaction is not immediate. It is asynchronous.` That's the important thing. I have to call `executePendingTransactions()` then the onCreateView is called and all works fine. I updated my first post. Thank you for your help.

Comment: If I want to navigate back and do it with the code above I create again a new Object. Do I have to delete them anyway in the activity? I'm scared that I fill the memory until it stops if I change the fragment to often. Can that happen? Do I have to do anything after the change? In my eyes it is a kind of recursion.

Comment: @Cilenco: Again, I have never tried doing what you are doing, and so I do not know all of its ramifications.