# Android CardFlip animation to exchange Fragments

Tags: android, android-animation

I know that this answer tells how to display a cardflip between two layouts,

[Displaying card flip animation on old android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16030667/displaying-card-flip-animation-on-old-android)

but how can I display a flip between 2 fragments added in my onCreate method?
Thanks

Comment: with thr support-library, you can just use the old way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used the support library. Thanks bofredo :)